# Split() skips NewLine in python

Tags: python, split, strip

> Note: In File "\n" is used for New Line its length is 1 and "\\n" is used for string "\n" its length is two.

When I give `Line="Some thing\n"` after `Line.split()` it gives list of Words ["Some","thing"] and skip `\n` It does not give `thing\n`. I have not used `strip()` function it do it by default. ordinary strip() function is used to skip `\n` from end of line.

check.txt:

```
abc abc abc \\n abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc

abc abc abc
```

My Code Is:

```
fileread=open("check.txt","r")
for line in fileread:
     print("Line:",line , "lenght :",len(line))
     words=line.split()                  #It Skip NewLine by Default
     print("Words List in Line:",words)
```

OutPut:

```
Line: abc abc abc \\n abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
 lenght : 68
Words List in Line: ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', '\\\\n', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc']
Line:
 lenght : 1
Words List in Line: []
Line: abc abc abc
 lenght : 12
Words List in Line: ['abc', 'abc', 'abc']
```

My Question is, Can Split function is able to strip Special Characters from Line by default?
Why Line:"\n" Does not create list ["\n"] and it creates empty list []

Comment: where is the problem mate?

Comment: Your output shows that the file contains the actual characters `"\\n"`, not a newline character. Iterating over a file already feeds input as one line per iteration, you're _never_ going to see a newline character except at the end when you say `for line in fileread:`.

Comment: My Question is, Can Split function is able to skip Special Characters from Line by default? Why Line:"\n" Does not create list ["\n"] , after line.split(),it creates empty list [] ,Why It skip "\n" I have not used  line.split("\n").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split() Function Split all these characters by default.Description in [Link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
Representation  Description
\n             Line Feed
\r             Carriage Return
\r\n           Carriage Return + Line Feed
\v or \x0b     Line Tabulation
\f or \x0c     Form Feed
\x1c           File Separator
\x1d           Group Separator
\x1e           Record Separator
\x85           Next Line (C1 Control Code)
\u2028         Line Separator
\u2029         Paragraph Separator
```

Python Code is

```
>>> data= "dsddddd\ndasdasd\ndasdasdas\nasfsafs\n"
>>> print(data.split())
['dsddddd', 'dasdasd', 'dasdasdas', 'asfsafs']
>>> data="aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa"
>>> print(data.split())
['aaaaaaaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaaaa']
>>> data= "dsddddd\rdasdasd\rdasdasdas\rasfsafs\r"
>>> print(data.split())
['dsddddd', 'dasdasd', 'dasdasdas', 'asfsafs']
>>> data= "dsddddd\u2029dasdasd\u2029dasdasdas\u2029asfsafs\u2029"
>>> print(data.split())
['dsddddd', 'dasdasd', 'dasdasdas', 'asfsafs']
>>>
```